# Big O notation for Following Loops

Tags: algorithm, math, time-complexity, big-o

What will be the Big Oh of these portion of codes:

```
int sum = 0;

for(int i = 1; i < N; i *= 2)

for(int j =0; j <i; j++)

sum++;
```

And

```
int sum = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < N; i *= 2)

for(int j =0; j <i; j++)

sum++;
```

My Attempt:
According to me both have time complexity equal to O(n^2), because here we will multiply n with n which is equal to n^2. Am I correct? Or doing some mistake?

Comment: So What will be its Big O?

Answer (score 2):

For the first portion of code:

1st loop will go from 1 to n with variable i going as
1, 2, 4, 8, 16.... n
and in the second loop j goes from 0 to i so the time complexity will be

O(1 + 2 + 4 + 8 + 16.... n) = O(2n - 1) = O(n)

and as for the second portion of code

i starts from 0, it always be 0 because you are multiplying it by 2. Its an infinite loop.

Comment: This is loop inside loop i.e nested loop. So should it not be n * n=O(n^2)??  If we do not consider it as nested loop then it should be O(n). Isn't it?

Comment: I have considered it as nested loop only, try to do it manually with some small n.